# Brainstorm dynamic process flow with php

Tags: php

I'm wondering if you can help me get started with a project, if there is already something else out there (in any language) that is opensource that I can study the code that would be great.

What I want to do is create a process flow like this: http://www.ifitjams.com/starting.htm#starting%200 and then have the app 'learn' from its users if the outcome works or if it doesn't to dynamically create the next process from there input. So in the car example above they could say after ending the process flow at 'x' it didn't work but I changed the alternator and it worked. So when the next person comes along and reaches point 'x' instead of the system running out of ideas it can suggest to change the alternator.

Just finding it hard to map out how I would have this app work and interact with a database to achieve this.

Comment: Well, make each point where a decision can take place a hypertext document, offer links below for the next step(s) and then ask if it worked. If not, leave a link back. Statistics you can add over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine saving the point of failure, and what was done to fix it. Than generate a report with a failure point based SELECT query, grouped by solutions.

As for the generation of flow charts, it's trivial with some good OOP (inheritance was practically made for this). Have an abstract class for `Node`, and have all other types on nodes inherit from that (i.e. `class Process extends Node`).

I haven't dealt with image generation before, but that's still far away. First, you need to create the layout structure for your data, then generate reports from it.

Comment: Libraries for creating flowcharts exist and I guess that the flowchart is less the cause of headaches.

Comment: Same, I just wanted to point out how I would have gone about.

Comment: Sure, just commenting, maybe TS is shedding some more light in here before the question get's closed because of beign off-topic as it is not programming related but guidance related (which item to shop for this problem).

Comment: yeah sorry guys if its not on topic was having a brain freeze on the best way to go with this, just needed a few pointers to get me back on track so thank you